# Restart Function That Is Running

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a function that calls a test on each object.  I want to be able to retest if the current test fails.

```
        foreach (TestObject test in Tests)
        {
              test.RunTest()
        }
        //This is in the TestObject class
        RunTest()
        {
             if (failure)
             {
                 //Want to be able to run RunTest() again without interrupting the foreach loop.
             }
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For both answers above, the solutions will result in RunTest() running forever if the failure is legitimate (i.e. not a transient failure, which I can only guess is what you're hitting).  You may consider doing one of the loops above, but instead keep a count of how many failures and bail out once that threshold is reached.  Something like:

```
int FailureThreshold = 3;
foreach (TestObject test in Tests) 
{
    int failCount = 0;

    while (failCount < FailureThreshold)
    {
        if (test.RunTest())
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            failCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

You should also consider keeping statistics for how many times you need to loop in order to pass.  This could be a great indicator of test stability.

Answer (score 5):

You guys like too much code...

```
for (var tryCount = 0; tryCount < 3; tryCount++)
    if (test.RunTest())
        break;
```

*... oh I thought of an even shorter version... but it's not as clean ...*

```
for (var tryCount = 0; !test.RunTest() && tryCount < 3; tryCount++);
```

If you want reuse then something like this...

```
static bool RunTest(Func<bool> testCase, int maxRetry)
{
    for (var tryCount = 0; tryCount < maxRetry; tryCount++)
        if (testCase())
            return true;
    return false;
}

// usage
var testResult = RunTest(test.RunTest, 3);

// or even...
var testResult = RunTest(
    {
        try {
            return test.RunTest();
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            return false;
        }
    }, 3);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could go about doing this, depending on why exactly you want to do this. You could:

1) Have `RunTest()` return `boolean` for success or failure, and then:

```
foreach (TestObject test in Tests)
{
    while(!test.runTest(){}
}
```

2) Use a `while` inside of `RunTest()`:

```
RunTest()
{
  while(true)
  {
    ...test stuff...

    if(failure)
      continue;
    else
      break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (TestObject test in Tests)
{
      test.RunTest()
}
//This is in the TestObject class
RunTest()
{
     //set it to failure or set variable to failure
     while (failure)
     {
         //do the test
         //if using variable set it to failure if it failed, success if it succeeded 
         //will keeping going through the while statement until it succeeds or you cut it off another way
     }
     // has succeeded
}
```